# Modify certbot manually created certificate

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm moving my website to a new server (debian9+apache).

I've installed a certbot certificate for my domain via command:

```
sudo certbot certonly -d www.theartstory.org --manual --preferred-challenges dns
```

I've used this command insead of:

```
sudo certbot --apache
```

because at that date DNS records were configured to old ip adress.

Now I need to add not-www version to this certificate. I've found a command to do this:

```
sudo certbot certonly --cert-name www.theartstory.org -d www.theartstory.org,theartstory.org
```

but it fails with error:

```
Client with the currently selected authenticator does not support any combination of challenges that will satisfy the CA. You may need to use an authenticator plugin that can do challenges over DNS.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

use CMD  下面 ：

```
sudo certbot certonly -d "*.yourdomain.xx" -d yourdomain.xx --manual --preferred-challenges dns-01 --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```

This is how I solved the problem

reason：Wildcard Certificates want to use DNS to renew